# Firebase how can I check for changes for all child nodes but one?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase realtime db structure like so:

```
/users
 -uid
   -34523623452
      c: array
      n: string
   -23452345435
   -77453534535
   history
      h: array
 -uid
 -uid
 -uid
```

I'm using this code to check for changes on content of current user:

```
ref.child(uid).on('value', function(snapshot){
      if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
        // do stuff
```

this way though it also fires up when any changes occur in the `history` node, because it's under the UID node too, I'd want to avoid that. How can I do without modifying the database tree?

Comment: You can't.  Firebase docs: "The value event is called every time data is changed at the specified database reference, including changes to children."

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by the Firebase docs, you should avoid using this data structure. You better create another node to store the user history and refer to the user by its uid:

```
/users
 -uid
   -34523623452
      c: array
      n: string
   -23452345435
   -77453534535

/history
 -id
   uid
   ...
```

More info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

Comment: I see, doesn't the structure use more space this way though?

Comment: It may use a little more space indeed. But if you think everytime you retrieve a user object, in your first structure, you get also its history, this would result in more data being downloaded. It'd make irrelevant the amout of space used by the recommend structure I think.